# Do contemporary non-Ashkenazim give challah to a kohen in chutz la’aretz?

Tags: kohen-priest, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, chutz-laaretz, separating-challah

Rambam [Hilchot Bikkurim 5:8 and 5:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.5.8?lang=bi) and Shulchan Aruch [Yoreh De’ah 322:4-5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.322.4?lang=bi) rule that in *chutz la’aretz* one can either:

- separate two *challot*, burn one and give the other to be eaten by any *kohen*
- separate one *challah* and give it to be eaten by a *kohen* who is not impure under the rubric of *tumah yotzeit migufo*.

Rema (ad loc.) notes a custom to separate only one *challah* and burn it. Contemporary *ashkenazi* practice seems to follow this custom.

What do contemporary *sefardim* / *mizrachim* / *teimanim* do with *challah* in *chutz la’aretz*? Do they in fact give *challah* to a *kohen* (in either of the two fashions described above)?

Comment: FWIW even some Ashkenazim do it sometimes (especially from Matza baking, cf. OC 557) and some Ashkenazi authorities reject the Rama entirely. In any event you are correct that it's highly unusual nowadays.

Comment: My personal experience having been present when challah was taken is that it is burned up like the Rem"a, even when taken by Sephardim

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29641/759

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan 322(16) wonders why the Shulchan Aruch says that, when he said in the Beis Yosef that the custom was not to give to a Cohen, even in his community (and so did the Rashba).